# 'import site' failed while trying to run UWSGI + virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, uwsgi

I have installed Python 2.7 on CentOS and created a virtualenv for my project using:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python2.7 venv
```

I have installed uwsgi with virtualenv deactivated.

I have also installed uwsgi-plugin-python, as I was facing 'unavailable modifier requested:' issue.

nginx config:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///tmp/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name mysite;
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location /media  {
        alias /projects/mysite/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /projects/rebus/rebus/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

uwsgi ini file:

```
[uwsgi]

chdir  = /projects/mysite
module = mysite.wsgi
virtualenv  = /projects/mysite/venv
plugin = python
master = true
processes = 2
socket = /tmp/mysite.sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

Now when I launch it and try to access the website:

```
uwsgi --ini mysite_uwsgi.ini
```

I get the following log:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.11.1 (64bit) on [Wed Aug 19 12:01:22 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) on 21 July 2015 15:58:54
os: Linux-2.6.32-042stab084.12 #1 SMP Tue Nov 26 20:18:08 MSK 2013
nodename: vs23.wovz.net
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /var/run
detected binary path: /usr/sbin/uwsgi
chdir() to /projects/mysite
your processes number limit is 1024
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/mysite.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56)  [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)]
Set PythonHome to /projects/mysite/venv
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x12e7160
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 218304 bytes (213 KB) for 2 cores
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mysite/wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
    import os
ImportError: No module named os
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1106)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 1107, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 1108, cores: 1)
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
```

It looks like my virtualenv with Python 2.7 is not recognized and UWSGI fails to load my Django app. How can I fix that?

Comment: In `uwsgi.ini`, you have `virtualenv = ...` pointing to your venv. I my (working) config files this is specified by `home=...`

Comment: @henrikstroem you can use either here.

Comment: This is because uwsgi is compiled for Python 2.6. You cannot force it to use a virtual environment for Python 2.7, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This might also have to do with which version of Python uwsgi was compiled against. You'll see the same symptom (`'import site' failed`) on systems where the default Python is 2.7 if you create a virtual environment using `--python=python3` but use a `uwsgi` obtained via `pip install uwsgi` instead of `pip3 install uwsgi`.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you didn't install uwsgi module in your virtualenv

solution:

```
source /projects/mysite/venv/bin/activate 
pip install uwsgi
```

then rerun your uwsgi server and it maybe work